# Assembly GSM code not working, nothing sent via sms

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, intel, gsm

I have a project of a heartbeat sensor made by assembly, when the beat is lower than some value it sends a message to a mobile number via sms.

when simulating the code on proteus. it doesn't send anything and I don't know what to do.
The chip is AT89S52 (not intel 8952, my mistake sorry)

here is my code :

```
$INCLUDE(.\GSM.h)
$INCLUDE (AT89S52.inc)


ORG 0000H
        MOV TMOD,#20H           //TIMER 1, MODE 2
        MOV TH1,#-3             //9600 BAUD RATE
        MOV SCON,#50H           //8 BIT, 1 STOP, EN ENABLED
        SETB TR1

        MOV DPTR,#MSG1
        ACALL H1
        ACALL DELAY
        MOV DPTR,#MSG2
        ACALL H1
        ACALL DELAY
        MOV DPTR,#MSG3
        ACALL H1
        ACALL DELAY
        MOV DPTR,#MSG4
        ACALL H1
        ACALL DELAY
        MOV DPTR,#MSG5
        ACALL H1
        ACALL DELAY
STAY: SJMP STAY
H1:     CLR A
        MOVC A,@A+DPTR
        JZ B1
        ACALL SEND
        INC DPTR
        SJMP H1
B1:
        RET
SEND:   MOV SBUF,A
H2:     JNB TI,H2
        CLR TI
        RET
DELAY:  MOV R3,#50H
HERE2:  MOV R4,#50H
HERE:   DJNZ R4,HERE
        DJNZ R3,HERE2
        RET


ORG 300H
MSG1: DB "AT",0DH
      DB 0H
MSG2: DB "AT+CMGF=1",0DH
      DB 0H
MSG3: DB "ATE=0",0DH
      DB 0H
MSG4: DB "AT+CMGS=",'"8149111111"',0DH
      DB 0H
MSG5: DB "TEXT",0X1A
      DB 0H


END
```